# PC 90s 2D Platformer Puzzler Indie Exit Levels With Robot

Tags: gaming, identify-this-game

**Platform(s):** PC (Used to play on Windows 95/98)

**Genre:** 2D Platformer, Puzzler, Indie, Overcome some square obstacles, Exit to door or portal next level (100 levels approx if not a bit less or more)

**Estimated year of release:** 90s (Possibly more towards end of 90s early 2000s)

**Graphics/art style:** Retro Squares like the world of Minecraft, brown squares and snow squares(Mainly tiny pixel squares and some big)

**Notable characters:** You play as a grey robot

**Notable gameplay mechanics:** You move left to right, maybe jump and possibly use a grappler hook. You could place puzzle pieces in water but the robot died when he touched the water. I'm not sure whether the robot would start walking right after you placed all the elements or if you had to click something for him to start walking. Basically the robot was on the left side and you had to build a way for him to get to the right side. I think that the pieces fell from the sky like in tetris and you had to place every piece in the right place to make a way for the robot. There were also elevators there and maybe teleports. There were also passwords that you got at each level so you could go to that level directly next time you played instead of starting new game everytime.

**Other details:** I really hope someone knows! I've not known the name of the game and haven't played in 20 years! I have found other 2D Robot platform games but none matched so this is going to be a tricky find! You play as a robot, I think you start from the left of the screen, and have to exit to the right! The game was simple, so you can move and jump over square obstacles! As the levels progress they got more tricky, and you had to dodge and move over more square obstacles, and square brown levels eventually became snow levels, so maybe cause the robot to slide. Maybe you used a grappler hook to dodge/move quicker. Any ideas anyone? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of MS-DOS tile based puzzle shareware games but this sounds a lot like **Hubie**.

[image]

You play a little alien that has to navigate a block-based world with items like vines, bricks, dynamite and head to an exit.

Hubie can move left-right, jump up a single tile and helicopter over single tile gaps.

Comment: It may be a MS-DOS game, or development from that game, but I'm afraid it is not that game. Although it is similiar, the game was simpler. You play as a robot, not an alien. I will look at more MS-DOS Games. I remember playing the game on Windows 95/98. Thanks so much for you reply anyway

Answer (score 0):

A lot of your description reminds me of Chip's Challenge (DOS/Windows), although you don't play as a robot... Perhaps this will help someone who searches for a similar game if nothing else.

[image]

Comment: Sorry it is not this game, more indie 2d style but close